# How to resume Fiber non blocking?

Tags: ruby

How two fibers could be run concurrently?

```
f1 = Fiber.new { sleep 1 }
f2 = Fiber.new { sleep 1 }

start = Time.now
f1.resume
f2.resume
p (Time.now - start).round # => 1
# Maybe rewrite as somethin like
# f1.non_blocking_start
# f2.non_blocking_start
# f1.blocking_await
# f2.blocking_await
```

P.S.

In JS (TypeScript) it could be done as in the code below, I wonder how it could be done in Ruby, as Fibers are pretty much same thing as Async in JS.

```
function sleep(ms: number): Promise<void> { 
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve())) 
}

let f1 = async function(): Promise<void> { await sleep(1000) }
let f2 = async function(): Promise<void> { await sleep(1000) }

async function main() {
  let p1 = f1()
  let p2 = f2()

  await p1
  await p1
}
main()
```

Comment: For non-blocking fibers you have to set a scheduler via [`Fiber.set_scheduler`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Fiber.html#method-c-set_scheduler). Ruby doesn't provide one, but there are 3rd party gems and also a test implementation: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/test/fiber/scheduler.rb